# matlab, plots in different rows

Tags: matlab, plot, rows

I have a long dataset (10 year-long): I would like to plot it but it's unclear.
I'm trying to plot one year under the other so that I would get "10 rows" of plot in the same image.

How can I do it?

Update: I meant this https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/125348-stack-plot-or-multiple-y-plot

Comment: What size does the dataset have? Is it a matrix or a vector?

Comment: It is a vector. It's difficult to explain. 
I found this (just now): https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/125348-stack-plot-or-multiple-y-plot
and the end of the first plot should correspond with the beginning of the second. I'll try this explanation as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming

- You have the data in a vector;
- The length of that vector is a multiple of `10`;
- Sample time is constant throughout the vector.

In that case, it's simple: [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the data into a 10-column matrix and [`plot`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) it, which will treat each column independently.

```
data = conv(rand(1,1100),ones(1,101),'valid'); % example data, 1x1000
plot(reshape(data,[],10), 'linewidth', 1)
grid on
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but it's not what I want to do. In don't want to overlap them, the second year should be under the first with another y-axis. I added something on the comments.

Comment: I couldn't do what you advice because of leap years, the arrays dimension is different.

Comment: I see. That involves more work. I'll keep this answer undeleted in case it's useful for other people. Can't you use `subplot`? That wastes some space around the axes, though

Comment: I looked for the answer all yesterday but I could not describe it properly to get the answers... In found that link accidentally. I'm going to try it in few days and add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've finally found out.

The command is "subplot" https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html

It's shortly described in the end of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4ql_fFk8DQ and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fayGDq_JKYE

In my case I can use

```
subplot(10,1,1)
plot(Xyear1,Ydataset(Xyear1))
subplot(10,1,2)
plot(Xyear2,Ydataset(Xyear2))
```

and so on...